# XCode 4.2 with multiple Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: ios6, xcode4.2

I thought this should be asked but turned out it hasn't been.

So my question is: I have a project which generate a series of products, in old XCode I specified loading image, i.e. the Default.png and Default@2x.png for each target, and it worked well. Now due to the tall screen I had to add another Default-568h@2x.png to each target. But every time I added one in the target->summary pane, xcode copies this Default-568h@2x.png to my project folder. And when I added another 568h image for another target, the old one is replaced. How can I specify different Default-568h@2x.png for different targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `info.plist` file (there is a separate one for each target), you can set these:

> [image: plist]

This is the 'base name' for the target's launch image. For example, I have `SplashScreenPro.png` *(non-Retina 3.5")*, `SplashScreenPro@2x` *(Retina 3.5")*, and `SplashScreenPro-568h@2x` *(4" Retina)*.

For my Lite target, I have Launch image set to `SplashScreenLite.png`, and I have `SplashScreenLite.png` *(non-Retina 3.5")*, `SplashScreenLite@2x` *(Retina 3.5")*, and `SplashScreenLite-568h@2x` *(4" Retina)*.

It turns out that the Summary part of Xcode is smart enough to pay attention to these attributes, meaning you don't have to manually name the files.